# docker run with cd command fails with executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

I want to execute this command:

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar
```

like described here http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

However I get the following error:

```
exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container a5da18532a63195f421757ab294c8fab82cd8e8beccb1ef29998d4b8b1293b43: [8] System error: exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin, not a command.  You would expect this error if Docker were running the command verbatim rather than through shell.  Maybe `... sh -c "cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read Backup and restore with docker  http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes you may encounter the problem that the command

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar
```

is not working what is strange because the command is suggested by docker. It will give the error:

```
exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH
```

A simple solution is to wrap the cd command:

```
sh -c "cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar"
```